# Filter list by condition as nested element inside an element

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to return a list of users that filters their specific roles. A user can have several roles, but the user list always exclude users who have one of roles as 'PRIMARY'. I included two conditions in `where()` method but the list only filters the first condition.

```
  IList<Account> users = _context.Account.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(a => a.Profile)
    .Include(a => a.AccountRole)
    .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
    .Where(a => (a.Organization == "My Company") && 
          (a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name != "PRIMARY")))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `!a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name == "PRIMARY")` is ***very*** different from `a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name != "PRIMARY")`

Comment: Oh yeah, foolish me. Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name != "PRIMARY")
```

Written like this, it means

> all the users which have at least one role not being "PRIMARY"

What you want instead is:

```
!a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name == "PRIMARY")
```

> all the users which do not have any role being "PRIMARY"

Comment: Nice explanation. 1+

Answer (score 1):

> exclude users who have one of roles as 'PRIMARY'

So, following the logic: it must be.

```
IList<Account> users = _context.Account.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(a => a.Profile)
    .Include(a => a.AccountRole)
    .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
    .Where(a => !a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name == "PRIMARY") // can't contain a role PRIMARY 
        && a.Organization == "My Company")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn Cam on for voting

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the second condition the where clause. Could you try changing it as :

```
IList<Account> users = _context.Account.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(a => a.Profile)
    .Include(a => a.AccountRole)
    .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
    .Where(a => (a.Organization == "My Company") && 
          (! a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name == "PRIMARY")))
    .ToList();
```

This may work as the second condition will only work if there is no "PRIMARY" role in the  AccountRole.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the `a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name != "PRIMARY")` to `!a.AccountRole.Any(r => r.Role.Name != "PRIMARY")`.

Comment: This has been answered **three times** before you posted this 4th version of the same answer. *And*, you got it wrong by keeping that `!=`